# Implementation of RFC 6951 "Encapsulation of SCTP inside UDP" as a C library

Tags: open-source, library, networking, c

Are there any open source libraries that implements [RFC 6951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6951), allowing applications to use SCTP even if it is not enabled in kernel or is blocked by NAT by encapsulating it in UDP?

Answer (score 2):

usrsctp will provide the functionality you are looking for.

https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp

Description from the project:

> This is a userland SCTP stack supporting FreeBSD, Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.

Language: C
[License](https://github.com/sctplab/usrsctp/blob/master/LICENSE.md): open source with attribution